# divs pushing out the bottom of table column in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I am working on a layout for a new website that I am building. Everything looks fine in chrome but for some reason in firefox my divs are pushed down about 600px and overlap other table rows as if they are not bound by their parent. For an example, check out thebrewtracker.com

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you writing this in tables?

Comment: I find trying to line things up using tables is easier than trying to relatively position divs all over the place... *shrug*

Comment: It may be easier for you and it may be your personal preference but for the age of development I would suggest learning how to use more standardized HTML especially for a layout like this.

Comment: If you want to get technical (or pedantic) then I would have to say that a table is more standardized than CSS since all browsers know how to draw a table yet magically CSS is handled differently in every browser!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from brew.css (line3)

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

On a side note using tables for layout is a BIG No No in modern web development!

Comment: I would say Yo man. Go for tables. The power of CSS is claimed but never proven. Try a simple thing like horziontal and vertical alignment with CSS and you will kick you head. With tables it easy!

Comment: SirB ! Give the CSS code for aligning a div which does not have a defined width and height to align it vertically and horziontaly in the center of the page without any extra Divs with cross browser compatibility.